# distribute my own c++ library

Tags: c++

I have already create a static and dynamic library for c++ in ubuntu and I wanna know how I'm gonna distribute this library for others, so they can install it and use it with the same plateform (linux).
I have the file (.h) and files (.so and .a) for the librairy.
Please your help

Comment: You should create a package and upload it to a [PPA](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them). Also upload to githib so that people would be able to download your sources.

Comment: Depending on your audience, you can take inspiration from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_package_management_systems#Linux

Answer (score 0):

There're so many ways to share your libs.

One could be creating a github project, with CMakeLists (or other buid system), which would be able to build lib on other people platforms.

Don't forget about the license (: